# page within a page HTML - outer page doesn't change inner page can be scrolled

Tags: html, ajax, iframe

I have three columns [navigation][products][shopping cart]

I want the products section to be very long, so I can hit space bar and scroll down.  But when I scroll down I want the navigation and the shopping cart to not move.  What technique should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add overflow:scroll; to your products :)